# Could not establish trust relationship for SSL/TLS secure channel - Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows-server-2012-r2

I know that there is a lot of information about this error on StackOverflow and other resources, but it's working perfectly on my dev machine and now working on the customer environment Windows Server 2012. Here is my code.

```
public sealed class Certificates
{
    private static bool subscribed = false;

    private static Certificates instance = null;

    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    private Certificates() { }

    public static Certificates Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                    instance = new Certificates();
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }

    public void GetCertificatesAutomatically()
    {
        if (!subscribed)
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
                RemoteCertificateValidationCallback;
            //new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback((sender, certificate, chain, policyErrors) => { return true; });
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 |
                                                   SecurityProtocolType.Tls |
                                                   SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
                                                   SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 0;
            subscribed = true;
        }
    }

    private static bool RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        // Return true if the server certificate is ok
        if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
            return true;

        bool acceptCertificate = true;
        StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder("The server could not be validate for the following reason():");

        // The server did not present a certificate
        if ((sslPolicyErrors & SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNotAvailable) == SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNotAvailable)
        {
            msg.AppendLine("    - The server did not present a certificate.");
            acceptCertificate = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // The certificate does not math the server name
            if ((sslPolicyErrors & SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch) == SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch)
            {
                msg.AppendLine("    - The certificate name does not match the authenticated name.");
                acceptCertificate = false;
            }

            // There is som other problem with certificate
            if ((sslPolicyErrors & SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors) == SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors)
            {
                foreach (X509ChainStatus item in chain.ChainStatus)
                {
                    if (item.Status != X509ChainStatusFlags.RevocationStatusUnknown &&
                        item.Status != X509ChainStatusFlags.OfflineRevocation)
                    {
                        SLICLog.Error($"    - {item.StatusInformation}.");
                        break;
                    }
                    if (item.Status != X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError)
                    {
                        msg.AppendLine($"    - {item.StatusInformation}.");
                        acceptCertificate = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // if validation failed, write log
        if (!acceptCertificate)
        {
            acceptCertificate = true;
        }

        return acceptCertificate;
    }
}
```

then I used the next code

```
 Host = new Uri(credential.Domain);

 if (Host.Scheme.Contains("https"))
     Certificates.Instance.GetCertificatesAutomatically();
using (HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = httpRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            using (var response = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(response))
            {
                token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SessionInternal>(sr.ReadToEnd());
                if (token != null)
                {
                    Authorized = true;
                    token.Exprired = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(token.expires_in));
                }
            }
```

The problem is that ServerCertificateValidationCallback being ignored on the environment machine (I know it from log that I have added just for debugging).

On the one website, I read that Microsoft does not allow this to ignore self-signed certificates on Server machines, but not sure. The same code works on Windows10 and does not work on Windows Server 2012 and also settings for API server the same too, I mean the host url and credentials are identical.
.NET Framework 4.7.2

**UPDATED:**

I don't know why, but another server with a self-signed certificate works, I mean I run the code on the environment server to work with another API server (it's another kind of API) and ServerCertificateValidationCallback delegate is called. I have tried to research network via Wireshark and that is a part of a bad connection between client/server[image]
And this is a normal connection with another server[image]
I'm confused but same code and only different IP of API servers and different behavior

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue - also Windows 10 works fine, Server 2012 R2 does not.  I've tried everything from .Net 4.6 to 4.7.2 to 4.8 and it works OK in Win 10 but not Win Server 2012 R2.  This is from a client perspective (i.e. the Win Server 2012 R2 runs client software that fails).  The site I am accessing has a valid GoDaddy TLS 1.2 only certificate.